Problemas con Flask
Buen día, tengo un problema con Flask. Deseo ejecutar flask con el comando
python server.py 

Si tengo un archivo llamado server.py
En terminal y me sale lo siguiente:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory

Cuando quiero ejecutar flask en mi carpeta al momento de la instalación me sale lo siguiente:
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock  

He tratado de localizar la dependencia pero no la encuentro. ¿Qué me recomiendan hacer?
Gracias y disculpen la redacción, soy nueva usando Flask.

Parece que intentas ejecutar flask con el comando: python server.py, pero supodre que no tienes un archivo server.py en el directorio. Aquí esta el problema, para ejecutar flask en el directorio actual lo puedes hacer o creando un archivo python que importe flask y lo use (se ejecuta con python you_file.py). Guardas el archivo de tu servidor y lo ejecutas con python flask run

Hola! Si tengo un archivo llamado server.py n.n Gracias!

¿Has instalado flask "pip install Flask"? y que dependencia tienes en tu archivo server.py?. Porfavor actualiza la pregunta, asi solo podemos adivinar.

La tengo instalada. Me sale lo siguiente: Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (2ba9bb). No entiendo por qué no puedo ejecutar flask, me sale como no tuviese instalado el entorno. Gracias por la ayuda y disculpa la poca claridad, soy nueva en esto n.n

Hmm, muestra un poco del código. Creo que usas pipenv. Que es una biblioteca para instalar dependencias.

El error [Errno 2] No such file or directory no es del sistema operativo. Diría que viene de una llamada a open() dentro de Python, por lo que es de suponer que tu script se comienza a ejecutar y falla. Junto al mensaje de error, se imprime información de dónde se realiza esta llamada. Coloca esta información como parte de la pregunta (muy importante la pila de llamadas). También el trozo relevante de código que venga de la referencia de dicho error.
